# Connection between $\textbf E$ and $\textbf D$ can be non-local ? - Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

In J.D. Jackson's first chapter, he says the proper equation connecting $\textbf E$ and $\textbf D$

$$ D_\alpha = \sum_\beta \int d^3x'\int dt' \epsilon_{\alpha\beta}(\textbf x',t')E_\beta(\textbf x - \textbf x',t-t') $$

He suggests that this is because the connection between these two can be non-local. What is author referring to here ? The direct relation is given in the momentum space,

$$ D_\alpha(\textbf k,\omega) = \sum_\beta \epsilon_{\alpha\beta}(\textbf k,\omega) E_\beta(\textbf k,\omega) $$

Answer (score 2):

Normally we assume the displacement field **D** depends exactly on the electric field **E** at the same spatial point, **D**(**r**) = \epsilon **E**(**r**). This is the local response. More generally, **D**(**r**) depends on **E** both at **r** and in the neighborhood, i.e., nonlocal response. That's why you have **E**(**r** - **r**') in the integral. After spatial Fourier transform you will get the relation between **D** and **E** in **k** space, which correspondingly shows **k** dependence.

Comment: Thanks ! But, precisely my question would be why **D** depends on **E** at **r'** also ?

Comment: Nonlocality is a quantum effect. Any physical wavefunction (of whatever object) has finite spatial extent. Within this finite volume D and E are quantum mechanically correlated even though they are not located at a same point.

Comment: You are very sure that this is not any classical effect ?! Because, Jackson's writes right in the first chapter of his text.

Comment: Yes, Jackson's book has lots of advanced stuff in the first chapter. I wouldn't say I understand very well that chapter :p

Answer (score 0):

The relation between the $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf D$ fields is via the polarization of some material. You might well imagine that the alignment of dipole moments in the material extends beyond the scope of the previous electric field.

As an example imagine a homogenous $\mathbf E$ field with a sharp cutoff plane. Due to polarization effects, there could be a $\mathbf D$ field even beyond the cutoff plane.

Comment: Am sorry cutoff plane as in cutoff of **E** ?